# Get rid of "_anonymous_0" tooltips in SVG with GraphViz

Tags: graphviz

I generate SVGs using Graphviz. When embedded in HTML, the nodes, edges and arrows show an "_anonymous_0" tooltip. Can I get rid of these from within GraphViz?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If your dot source start something like this:

```
digraph {
```

it may help to use the following:

```
digraph "" {
```

It looks like the name of the graph (`digraph mygraph {` ) is transformed to a title element (`<title>mygraph</title>`). If you omit the name, *anonymous_0* is used instead. But if *""* is used, no title element is being created.

There may be a better solution to this though...

Comment: Sadly, [there does not seem to be a better solution for Graphviz or SVG in general](https://discourse.wicg.io/t/disable-svg-tooltips-with-title-pointer-events-none/1054).

Answer (score 14):

Found by trial and error :-)

```
digraph "my title" {
tooltip=" "
node [tooltip=" "]
edge [tooltip=" "]
...
}
```

disables the automatic generation of tooltips.

---

an empty string

```
tooltip=""
```

does not(!) disable the generation.

Comment: This answer is better than the selected one, because it allows you to set the title of the svg (which is shown as the title in your browser tab) but also eliminate the tooltip in blank areas of the graph.

Comment: Seems to no work for 2.40.1, there a tooltip with one space is generated instead.