# How do I generate an SVG file without the <title> element?

Tags: svg, graphviz, dot

I am using dot to generate SVG files but I'd like to remove the  element from its nodes since I am using a script to show other information at mouse over.

Is it possible to tell dot not to generate such elements?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get rid of "\_anonymous\_0" tooltips in SVG with GraphViz](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7221127/get-rid-of-anonymous-0-tooltips-in-svg-with-graphviz)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a workaround I used jQuery to remove the title elements from the SVG I embedded in my page